# How can I use Maven to run only previously failed JUnit 5 tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I have a set of autotests on junit 5, maven, java. I need to write a script or method that checks if there are failed tests from previous execution. And if there are such tests, then run them.

In my TestWatcher I get a list of fallen tests, but I don't understand how to tell maven to only run them. I know of an option to run tests via mvn test -Dtest="TestClass1, TestClass2", but this is not an option if there are, for example, 20 tests.

The @RepeatedTest junit annotations, as well as the surefire rerunFailingTestsCount property, are not appropriate because they are triggered immediately on a dropped test. Which is good, of course, but not for this specific task.

Comment: What does dropped test mean? Failed? Skipped? Interrupted? Brand new tests?

Comment: Oh, I apologize for the inaccuracy. I was only referring to failed tests. The ones that didn't pass last time.

Comment: This is what an IDE is good at

Comment: and this is what maven seems to be bad at) but the problem remains

Comment: While you can do it for "multi modules" (`mvn <args> -rf :my-module` ..at least is logged after a failed mm-build), there seems no such option on test base..

Comment: @xerx593 Oh, well, at least it potentially works somewhere) thanks

Comment: the closest (but far from desired) I could get with maven-surefire: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html Hi & Welcome! :)

Comment: @xerx593 thank you, also glad to meet) but rightly pointed out - far from the desired)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, there is an option to run specific tests using LauncherFactory. But there is another option, which is not particularly designed for a large number of tests.
In summary - I catch the failed tests and write them to the file. Then I go through them and substitute them in the mvn test command. This is what the implementation looks like:

1. This utility writes each value obtained to a file

   ```
    public static void writeLine(final String value, final String filepath) throws IOException {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filepath, true)) {
        fileWriter.append(value);
        fileWriter.append("\n");
        fileWriter.flush();
    }
   ```
2. In the **testFailed** method of the **class that implements TestWatcher** I trigger writing the name of the fallen method to a file. FileUtils - the name of the class where the utility is located. Substring is needed to trim () from the method

   ```
       try {
        FileUtils.writeLine(context.getDisplayName().substring(0, context.getDisplayName().length() - 2),
                "failedTests"); }
   ```
3. Finally, I have a sh script that reads the file and flips through the name of the methods.And then clears the file

`filepath="failedTests.txt"
testclass="*Test#"
script=""
for var in $(cat $filepath)
do
  script+="${testclass}${var}, "
  done
mvn -Dtest="$script" test
true > "$filepath"`

The output will be a string like mvn -Dtest=*Test#failmethod1, *Test#failmethod2, " test. Running the script will only run the tests that fell in the last run.

filepath="failedTests.txt" - file, where the tests were recorded and where to take the dropped tests from.

I have all classes with the nameTest signature. So I use the *Test construct. That is, I select all classes. You can read about template-based class selection [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html). It also explains why the # symbol is needed (to choose a specific method).

true > "$filepath" - clean the file